# Convert a column which contains array of string (of unequal size) to exactly two columns with multiple rows in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in the format shown below

```
+----+---------+
|col1|col2     |
+----+---------+
|100 |[a, b, c]|
|200 |[b, c, d]|
|300 |[d, e]   |
+----+---------+
```

where *col1* contains integers and *col2* contains Array of strings. I need to convert *col2* into two columns with a string in each column as shown below

**Required format:**

```
+----+------+------+
|col1|col2_0|col2_1|
+----+------+------+
|100 |a     |b     |
|100 |a     |c     |
|100 |b     |c     |
|200 |b     |c     |
|200 |b     |d     |
|200 |c     |d     |
|300 |d     |e     |
+----+------+------+
```

i.e. for each row with *col2* having an array of strings of size *n*, there will be nC2 rows with two columns *col2_0*, *col2_1* and *col1* populated in the rows accordingly.

**My attempt**:
I have only been able to convert the *col2* into multiple columns as shown below, but am not able to do it in the format required.

```
+----+------+------+------+
|col1|col2_0|col2_1|col2_2|
+----+------+------+------+
|100 |a     |b     |c     |
|200 |b     |c     |d     |
|300 |d     |e     |null  |
+----+------+------+------+
```

If nothing works out, I am thinking of looping through the dataframe and adding elements to a Seq in the required format, but I don't think it is a good way to do this.

I hope the question is clear enough. Please let me know a good way to approach this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use UDF to get the required result:

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  // Sample dataframe
  val df = List(
    (100, List("a", "b", "c")),
    (200, List("b", "c", "d")),
    (300, List("d", "e"))).toDF("col1", "col2")

  // udf to get required combination
  val getCombinationUDF = udf((row: Seq[String]) => {
    row.combinations(2).toSeq
  })

  df.show(false)
  df.withColumn("col2", getCombinationUDF('col2))
    .withColumn("col2", explode_outer('col2))
    .select('col1, 'col2.getItem(0).as("col2_0"), 'col2.getItem(1).as("col2_1"))
    .show(false)
/*
+----+------+------+
|col1|col2_0|col2_1|
+----+------+------+
|100 |a     |b     |
|100 |a     |c     |
|100 |b     |c     |
|200 |b     |c     |
|200 |b     |d     |
|200 |c     |d     |
|300 |d     |e     |
+----+------+------+ */
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!